# SVG file how to resize when export it to svg file

Tags: svg

[image]

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="e639df27-0e42-4de9-9d05-d37458211c8a" data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 22 22"><defs><style>.f8f45c5e-663e-4aeb-8eb8-bdc5b008c6ac{fill:none;}.aa350ddd-b404-42d7-ac7b-d7365a85c785{fill:#327fbf;}</style></defs><title>dsadasd</title><path class="f8f45c5e-663e-4aeb-8eb8-bdc5b008c6ac" d="M11,7a5.92,5.92,0,0,1,.79-3c-.26,0-.52,0-.79,0a9,9,0,1,0,9,9c0-.27,0-.53,0-.79A5.92,5.92,0,0,1,17,13,6,6,0,0,1,11,7Z" transform="translate(-1 -1)"/><path class="aa350ddd-b404-42d7-ac7b-d7365a85c785" d="M23,7A6,6,0,0,0,12.43,3.11,11.19,11.19,0,0,0,11,3,10,10,0,1,0,21,13a11.19,11.19,0,0,0-.11-1.43A6,6,0,0,0,23,7Zm-3,6a9,9,0,1,1-9-9c.27,0,.53,0,.79,0A5.92,5.92,0,0,0,11,7a6,6,0,0,0,6,6,5.92,5.92,0,0,0,3-.79C20,12.47,20,12.73,20,13Zm.65-2.6A5,5,0,1,1,22,7,5,5,0,0,1,20.65,10.4Z" transform="translate(-1 -1)"/><rect class="aa350ddd-b404-42d7-ac7b-d7365a85c785" x="13" y="3" width="6" height="1"/><rect class="aa350ddd-b404-42d7-ac7b-d7365a85c785" x="13" y="5" width="6" height="1"/><rect class="aa350ddd-b404-42d7-ac7b-d7365a85c785" x="13" y="7" width="6" height="1"/></svg>
```

> Please see this image. This is what I'm trying to accomplished

[image]

> Can anyone help me how can I accomplished like on the image using svg.
> I want my svg icon look small like on the image. Currently the SVG code I've pasted on my snippet is to large. Can anyone help me how can i make it small like on the image I've provided. Thank you

Comment: the small icon is a png type. I want my SVG code to look like it on the image I've provided. I'm thinking if I convert the png file to SVG the icon is not pixelated like on the image and I think the image will much look detail in SVG. Please help e thanks

Comment: I really can't understand a thing from your question. You must be more specific and better explain what you are trying to achieve. If I can not understand can not help. Fix your question please.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after re looking in the question I think I understood. The only thing that made your svg too large was those weird and large css classes. Without that your svg is all the small in weight than it can be.
See the cleaned version

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 22 22">
<defs><style>.fill {fill:none;}.fill2{fill:#327fbf;}</style></defs>
<path class="fill" d="M11,7a5.92,5.92,0,0,1,.79-3c-.26,0-.52,0-.79,0a9,9,0,1,0,9,9c0-.27,0-.53,0-.79A5.92,5.92,0,0,1,17,13,6,6,0,0,1,11,7Z" transform="translate(-1 -1)"/>
<path class="fill2" d="M23,7A6,6,0,0,0,12.43,3.11,11.19,11.19,0,0,0,11,3,10,10,0,1,0,21,13a11.19,11.19,0,0,0-.11-1.43A6,6,0,0,0,23,7Zm-3,6a9,9,0,1,1-9-9c.27,0,.53,0,.79,0A5.92,5.92,0,0,0,11,7a6,6,0,0,0,6,6,5.92,5.92,0,0,0,3-.79C20,12.47,20,12.73,20,13Zm.65-2.6A5,5,0,1,1,22,7,5,5,0,0,1,20.65,10.4Z" transform="translate(-1 -1)"/>
<rect class="fill2" x="13" y="3" width="6" height="1"/><rect class="fill2" x="13" y="5" width="6" height="1"/><rect class="fill2" x="13" y="7" width="6" height="1"/></svg>
```

If you want to make it a little bit shorter you have to open it in Inkscape and convert the rects into paths and then select the whole elements and convert everything into one single path. It will remove also the transform translate.

Notice that once you save your icon Inkscape will add to the svg a lot of its own information which is not necessary for the svg display or performance. So you have to clean it up using SVGOMG service or doing it manually. For that simple icon I prefer the second. Just keep in mind to save your icon with a different name. Then open both, the original and the reshaped in the text editor and simply remove from the old one everything but the svg declaration, the styles and the path. The go to the new svg, find the **d="M2... Z"** stuff, copy it and substitute in the old svg. This way you will fastly do the job.